# VBA why must I dim a class variable as a variant, not as its type?

Tags: vba, excel

In an Excel macro, I have a function defined like to return a Recordset like so

```
Function GetCommissionDataRecordset(doctorCode As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    Set GetCommissionDataRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    .
    . ' setup the connection and SQL string...
    .
    GetCommissionDataRecordset.Open strSQL
end function
```

and I attempt to call the function like so

```
sub tester()
    'Dim oRecSet As ADODB.Recordset  ' this doesn't work, needs to be a variant
    Dim oRecSet As Variant
    Set oRecSet = GetCommissionDataRecordset("GC")
    'Copy Data to Excel'

    ActiveSheet.Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset (oRecSet)
end sub
```

If in the `tester` subprocedure I define `oRecSet as  ADODB.Recordset`, I get a runtime error when doing the `CopyFromRecordset`.

The error goes away when I define `oRecSet` as a `Variant`.

The runtime error is `430 Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface`.

When the error occurs, Watch tells me that the type of `oRecSet` is `Recordset/Recordset`

When I use the variant approach, Watch tells me that the type of `oRecSet` is `Variant/Object/Recordset`

Inspecting the properties of the object in Watch seems to show no difference to me.

What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CopyFromRecordSet expects a Variant parameter.  As you are (accidentally?) sending the recordset by value, because of the () around oRecSet, the type matching seems to be quite strict, causing an error.

If you change your call to:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset oRecSet
```

it will work when oRecSet is a RecordSet, but then you will not be forcing a By Value parameter passing.  Actually the function declaration doesn't specify if the parameter is ByVal or ByRef, but one wouldn't expect a "copy **from** recordset" method to change it's contents.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to, you just have to remove the parentheses

```
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset oRecSet
```